# How can Madara Uchiha use Susanoo when he does not have 2 mangekyou abilities in his eyes?

Tags: naruto

How can Madara Uchiha use Susanoo when he does not have 2 mangekyou abilities in his eyes?

Comment: He's just that good I guess.

Comment: And how are you so sure he doesn't have an ability in each eye. It could be that he was smart, and never revealed them, and they otherwise do not have obvious effects. I know at least one source had his eyes rotate, and he could see things back in time from a different angle, which was demonstrated in his fight against Hashirama. Such an ability would go completely unnoticed, and being smart, Madara wouldn't brag about it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it is not mentioned anywhere that Madara doesn't have two Mangekyou abilities in his Sharingan. It is simply not revealed just like Izuna's Mangekyou abilities.

Second, as mentioned on the [Wikia](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Mangeky%C5%8D_Sharingan),

> Once a user awakens the Mangekyō in both eyes, or the ability of both of their eyes, they are able to perform Susanoo

it is not necessary to have any abilities specific to their Mangekyou Sharingan in order to perform the Susanoo.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the rinnegan is an improvement of the sharingan it self, so by having a mangekyou and the rinnegan, he would be able to invoke susanno.
But the susanno is in fact a skill that can only be summoned while having two eyes, rinnegan and mangekyou. 
Sasuke have a rinnegan and mangekyou and is able to summon it.

Regarding the tsukuyomi and amaterasu I can't tell for sure. Right eye has the amaterasu and the left one has the tsukuyomi. I believe that Itachi explained this like this, but remember that kishimoto left some plot holes so we can't really be sure. Also, I think Sasuke used the amaterasu and the tsukuyomi while having only one mangekyou and one rinnegan.

Comment: Sasuke has the Amaterasu and Kagutsuchi, not Amaterasu and Tsukuyomi. Regardless, His Rinnegan does not remove his access to any of his Mangekyou abilities. Susanoo is unlocked by "mastering" the abilities each eye grants you.

Comment: You're right, my bad. I got confused since Sasuke used genjutsu while having its Mangekyou activated so I might thought that he actually had the tsukuyoumi

Comment: It actually makes me wonder if Itachi Knew or not that Mangekyou (literal translation: Kaleidoscope) Sharingan had different abilities for different wielders. It actually sounded like he didn't know that from how he worded it.  Regardless, I keep forgetting to rewatch Madara after he revives and looses both his eyes, to see if/when he uses Susanoo. I seem to recall him using it while he had no eyes at all, but can't clearly remember to be sure.

Comment: nope @Ryan he did not use susanoo after he was revived. he simply didn't need to, I guess. after he was revived he focused on getting his eyes and becoming a jinchouriki.